# How can I nest three inline markup blocks?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, kendo-ui, nested

I'm trying to nest three things within each other with Kendo UI - specifically, a div inside as the contents of a panelbar's items, which is in a tabstrip. I get this error: `Inline markup blocks (@<p>Content</p>) cannot be nested. Only one level of inline markup is allowed.`

I looked over this link: [Kendo widgets two level deep in Razor, inline markup blocks cannot be nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23386283/kendo-widgets-two-level-deep-in-razor-inline-markup-blocks-cannot-be-nested)

But I can't use this because the `@helper` directive was removed in ASP.NET Core, and that was a fix that was available to ASP.NET MVC. Are there any ways to get around this with .NET Core?

Here is the code at fault:

```
 @(
    Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
        .Name("Stages")
        .Items(stage => {
            stage.Add().Text("Confirm Selections").Content(@<text>
                @(
                    Html.Kendo().PanelBar()
                        .Name("Selections")
                        .Items(panelbar => {
                            panelbar.Add().Text("Selected ECUs")
                                .Content(@<div id="confirm" class="text-center"></div>);
                        })
                )
            </text>);
        }
    )
)
```

And the error again: `Inline markup blocks (@<p>Content</p>) cannot be nested. Only one level of inline markup is allowed.`

Any workaround?

Comment: What is the component you are attempting to create also? Why are you trying to create all of that directly in the View, can you not do a portion on the server and build an associative helper to assist? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the contents of the `PanelBar` with a string as such:

```
@(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
    .Name("Stages")
    .Items(stage => {
        stage.Add().Text("Confirm Selections").Content(@<text>
            @(Html.Kendo().PanelBar()
            .Name("Selections")
            .Items(panelbar => {
                panelbar.Add()
                    .Text("Selected ECUs")
                    .Content("<div id=\"confirm\" class=\"text-center\">Test data</div></text>");
                })
            )
        </text>);
    })
)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no ways to get around this that I can find.  It appears as this is actually a razor issue and not a Kendo UI issue.

https://www.telerik.com/forums/three-four-or-more-level-of-hierarchy-on-a-grid

I suggest submitting a ticket to Telerik to see if they could give you a more concrete answer.

Comment: I submitted that ticket to Telerik like you suggested, and they were able to send me back a working solution! I'll post it below for others to be able to use.